# HTML Calendar Disable Specific Dates

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui, bootstrap-4

I would like to some specific days in the HTML calendar. But I am facing the problem like below. The calendar with the blue box is not allowed the changes. However, another calendar that is on the backside can be changed by JavaScript code. I wonder why I cannot change anything on the first calendar.

For example, the first day can be changed on the backside but cannot in the default calendar.

[image]
[image]

Here is my code :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>The selected date is as follows: <input type="date" class="disableFuturedate"></p>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
      var currentDate = new Date();
      $('.disableFuturedate').datepicker({
      format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
      autoclose:true,
      firstDay :3
      
      });
   });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please elaborate more .

Comment: You are mixing jquery-ui's `datepicker` with the `HTML 5` date picker. Instead of input's `type="date"` use `type="text"` instead, assuming the datepicker will be used.

Comment: *Creating a datepicker on an `<input type="date">` is not supported due to a UI conflict with the native picker.* Please see: https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: Also you may want to see: https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay